# how to integrate $\int \frac {x^4}{x^4 +5x^2 +4} dx$

Tags: calculus

Could I have some help for this question?

$$\int \frac {x^4}{x^4 +5x^2 +4} \, dx$$

I've reduced the equation to...

$$\int \frac {1}{1 + 5x^{-2} + 4x^{-4}} \, dx$$

But I'm stuck after this step. Could I have some help for this question?

Comment: How about long division/partial fractions? The original denominator can be factored...

Comment: I've seen the exact same problem on here quite recently.  That and a harder problem...

Comment: @TheChaz, I've tried using partial fraction. But I could not get the numerator for the partial fractions. $(x^4 + 5x^2 = 4) = (x^2+\frac 52)^2 -(\frac 32)^2; x^4 = 4A-B +x^2 (A+B)$. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Honestly, it would probably save both of us much time if you would go to wolfram alpha and have it "show steps"...

Comment: @melyong: good. +1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Using partial fraction, you can write the integrand as

$$\frac {x^4}{x^4 +5x^2 +4}= 1+\frac{1}{3(x^2+1)} - \frac{16}{3(x^2+4)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $x^4+5x^2+4=(x^2+1)(x^2+4)$, change the initial integrand to a form only involving $\frac{1}{x^2+a}$.